# Intermittent performance issue with old questions, markdown and chat

Tags: bug, status-norepro, performance

**Update**
Okay, I still get this behavior, but it has something to do with this instance of Chrome vs. another. Which likely implies it has to do with cookies or something.
I realized this after starting chrome with another profile.

---

It seems to me that cached and recent content works fine, but I haven't been able to — for example — load [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096477/c-library-to-resize-an-image-with-content-aware-scaling-algorithm) all day today. Also, the markdown editor isn't working here, and I can't load any of the actual rooms on `chat.meta.stackoverflow.com`. Merge this if someone else is talking about the issues.

PS I'm on Chrome in a building full of networks in NYC.

```
 7  stackoverflow.com (64.34.41.58)  1.558 ms  1.477 ms  1.672 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  14 hops, 70 msec from the MidWest.  Every time I checked.  I'm not often pleased with my ISP.

Answer (score 2):

Are you having trouble getting to the CDN at http://sstatic.net ? We can't reproduce this.

Comment: I can also no longer reproduce this after restarting that particular instance of chrome. The behavior seemed to be as though scripts would never complete loading. I didn't get to test if I had an issue with sstatic.net, but the odd thing is, the other browser running when I did have the issue had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

If your ISP (or building or something) is blocking any content, you may be experiencing issues from that. At work they block things like Gravatar, Google Analytics, and things like that which do cause some issues for me on the SE sites. Could that be part of the problem? Possibly adblock might have an effect?

The page keeps spinning and spinning for about 30 seconds after it loads. I presume that something that is being retrieved is in the process of timing out.

Does your page load at all?

Comment: Thanks; the pages actually seemed to load most of the content, but never get around to rendering for older questions... questions of the day worked fine. I admit this is baffling.